# How to make data from applet secure?

Tags: java, security, ssl, applet

I created a Java applet that will perform some computing on client side and return data to the server. But I'm afraid that client can send me some wrong data.

So my question is: how I can guarantee that on server I receive data computed actually by my applet, and not some other data from some hacker? It's enough to make applet signed and run it over HTTPS (SSL)?

Comment: You almost certainly can't. You can do a lot to make it *hard* to fake the data, but that's all. The applet can be decompiled, so anything it does to encrypt the data can be replicated and faked. *(Not seeing why this question has been downvoted.)*

Answer (score 1):

> ..how I can guarantee that on server I receive data computed actually by my applet, and not some other data from some hacker?

You can't.

> It's enough to make applet signed and run it over HTTPS (SSL)?

No.  Nothing is enough.

A signed applet might provide some security to the byte-codes & SSL to the data of the client, but it will not protect the server from data that is not coming from the applet.